# Failure to refresh function Regextract(Filename()) every time Google sheet opens

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Google sheet that fails to load filename()](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dtmsFNqGMFpAwjsnKFBTR0AGwqW_MuXAxYGL6evPRag/edit?usp=sharing)

I use daily sheets with the name of each day like this:

**01 January 2023 Oncall_Endorsement_Sheet**

**02 January 2023 Oncall_Endorsement_Sheet**

**03 January 2023 Oncall_Endorsement_Sheet**, and so on..

I used to add the date in each sheet by using the function of :
`=REGEXEXTRACT(FILENAME(), "\d{2} .* \d{4}")`

Where filename function is in the Appscript:

```
function Filename() {  

return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
```

But it fails to run in most of the new sheets. Those sheets were created by (make a copy) to make multiple copies of the same sheet then I just rename the files to complete the whole month days. I Expect every time i open a new sheet, Regextract function works well according to the new renamed filename.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about recalculating your function of `=REGEXEXTRACT(FILENAME(), "\d{2} .* \d{4}")` to the cell "C6" of "CASES LIST" sheet? When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Filename() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}

const sample = _ => "Loading..."; // Dummy.

function onOpen(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("CASES LIST");
  const range = sheet.getRange("C6");
  const formula = `=REGEXEXTRACT(FILENAME(), "\\d{2} .* \\d{4}")`;
  range.setFormula("=sample()");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setFormula(formula);
}
```

- In this script, when the Spreadsheet is opened, `=REGEXEXTRACT(FILENAME(), "\d{2} .* \d{4}")` in the cell "C6" of "CASES LIST" sheet is recalculated by a simple trigger of OnOpen.

Comment: It works well if the sheet is opened from a PC while it fails again if the sheet is being opened by a mobile phone

Comment: @Hassan Almaateeq About your new question of `if the sheet is opened from a PC while it fails again if the sheet is being opened by a mobile phone`, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?